# Type of visa UK

Tags: united-kingdom, family

I want to ask which type of visa is better to apply for because I have a stable relationship (Not Married) with an European guy (I am not European and I need a visa to visit him in UK). Now we live together in Europe. He will work for 6 months in UK, but there exists a possibility that the contract will be extended for one year (or more), but it is only a possibility. I want to go with him no matter if the contract is extended or not. If they give me the visa I will live with him in UK.

In the case that the contract won't be extended, we will return to Europe, then that's why I don't want to search for a job in UK right now (and I don't think in short time I can find a job). But in the case that the contract will be extended, I want to stay with him, but I also want to work in the meantime (qualified work).

**I don't know which type of visa is better to apply for.** I was thinking 2 options, but If you know a better way, please tell me.

My options and my doubts about those options are:

**1) Apply for EEA family permit**

**a)** Do you think I'm eligible to ask for EEA family permit?

**b)** In the case that I apply for EEA family permit, Do you know if I can work in the meantime?

**c)** In the case that I apply for EEA family permit, If I cannot work in the meantime: 
  * Can I convert my visa to a working visa [only in the case his contract will be extended and I found a job (qualified job)]. 
  * Do I have to leave UK before the application of the working permit? 
  * How long do I have to stay outside UK before apply for a work permit?

**2) If I apply for a tourism visa, instead of the EEA family permit**

**a)** If I ask for a tourism visa, Can I ask right after a working visa in the case his contract will be extended and I found a job (qualified job)? Do I have to leave UK for some time before asking the working visa?

**b)** It would be a problem if I apply for a working visa right after my tourist visa expires (or before the tourism visa expires) ?

**If you know a better way, please let me know.**

Thank you so much.

Comment: They do not allow an in-country switch from visitor to work permit.

Comment: Thank you, and Do you think it is also a bad idea to ask first tourism and then EEA family permit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do you think I'm eligible to ask for EEA family permit?

Possibly.  If you are in a "durable relationship," you qualify.  My understanding is that the UK interprets this to mean that your relationship must be at least two years old.  If your relationship is older than that then you probably have a good chance of qualifying, especially if you have lived together for longer than two years.

> In the case that I apply for EEA family permit, Do you know if I can work in the meantime?

If you have an EEA family permit, you can work after you arrive in the UK.  (You cannot work in the UK while the application is pending because you won't be in the UK at that time.)

> I don't know which type of visa is better to apply for.

You cannot apply for a tourism visa because you are not intending to be a tourist.  There is a short-term [family visit visa](https://www.gov.uk/family-visit-visa), which would suit your needs if his contract is not extended.  Do not apply for a tourism visa, because you will be denied and it will look bad on your record.

If you do not qualify for an EEA family permit, and want to avoid potential problems if his contract is extended, the correct visa would be a [family of a settled person visa](https://www.gov.uk/join-family-in-uk).  These are very expensive (the cost is over £1000).

In conclusion, you should definitely try to qualify for the EEA family permit, since the conditions are much less burdensome, and the fee (or rather, the fact that there is no fee) is much more attractive.

Comment: Thank you so much.<br/> We are in a almost 3 years relationship and we are living together for one year an 5 months more or less. Do you think we have chance to apply for EEA family permit?<br/> And also, Do you think tourist is not the best idea, neither if I ask after the EEA family permit instead of the work permit?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check https://www.gov.uk/remain-in-uk-family/overview, as "family" includes partners

Comment: Thus is true, but the UK has a fairly strict criterion governing which partnerships they will accept as qualifying for this purpose. Also, the page you link to is for people already in the UK, which this person appears not to be.